# Adding google maps v2 to Fragment **UPDATED WITH CORRECT ANSWER**

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am using googles navigation drawer for my application and am trying to add google maps to it.

The code i have so far builds fine but when the map option in the menu (opens new fragment) is selected it crashes.

I cant seem to find any straight forward tutorials on how to do this so any help would be great :)

**UPDATED**

mapFrag class

```
public class mapFrag extends Fragment { 

   MapView mMapView;
  GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflate and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);




    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onResume();//needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());



        googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
        googleMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory. newLatLngZoom(new   LatLng(**,**) ,  14.0f) );



        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(isVisible());

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }


    //Perform any camera updates here




;

    return v;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}






}
```

.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
>

</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity Methods

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag = null;

    switch (position) {
    case 0:

        break;
    case 1:

        break;
    case 2:

        break;
    case 3:

        break;
    case 4:
        mapFrag = new fragName();
        break;
    case 5:


    case 6:


    default:
        break;
    }

    if (mapFrag != null){

FragmentManager mapFragManager = getFragmentManager();
mapFragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
    else{

        Log.e(null, "Error in creating fragment");
    }

    if (fragment != null) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");


    }
}
```

Manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.androidhive.slidingmenu"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<permission
    android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"                            
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
     >



    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
            <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
 android:value="**API KEY**" />
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat

```
12-02 12:16:51.910: W/ImageView(4863):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-02 12:16:51.910: W/ImageView(4863):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 12:16:58.540: D/AndroidRuntime(4863): Shutting down VM
12-02 12:16:58.540: W/dalvikvm(4863): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a361f8)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:347)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:382)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:374)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity.displayView(MainActivity.java:206)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:172)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity$SlideMenuClickListener.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:133)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4446)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-02 12:16:58.550: E/AndroidRuntime(4863):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 12:19:19.560: I/Process(4863): Sending signal. PID: 4863 SIG: 9
```

I am running this on a physical device running android 4.0.4

Comment: Is that your layout? Because you're trying to replace a fragment in a framelayout with id set to "R.id.frame_container" but I don't see it in your xml. You just have a fixed fragment of class SupportMapFragment.

Moreover, in case "mapFrag != null", in replace you're using "fragment".

Comment: got this working by getting rid of supportmapfragment, see updated class and layout file. i also had to add "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>" to the manifest.

Comment: Could you post the update code? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Please find updated code :), hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a fragment with a map in it:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment
```

mapview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
map:cameraZoom="12"
map:mapType="normal"
map:uiZoomControls="false"
map:uiRotateGestures="true"
map:uiScrollGestures="true"
map:uiZoomGestures="true"
map:uiTiltGestures="false" />
```

then in the fragment do this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview, container, false);
}
```

then to get the map instance:

```
private GoogleMap getGoogleMap() {
        if (map == null && getActivity() != null && getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()!= null) {
            SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview);
            if (smf != null) {
                map = smf.getMap();
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: Solid implementation :) Thanks

Comment: I followed this process..but I am getting null on map...what might be wrong..please help me.

Comment: and may I know what is the type of the "map". I mean is it GoogleMap type. I made it --  GoogleMap map;